# autoUpdater.setFeedURL is not a function

Tags: electron, auto-update, squirrel.windows

I'm attempting to implement windows auto update functionality in an electron app (which may lead to my early death) and I'm getting this error.

[image]

This is the URL I'm passing for testing purposes

EDIT: my electron app is using the two package.json structure and this code is in my app>main.js file

```
const feedURL = 'C:\\Users\\p00009970\\Desktop\\update_test';
autoUpdater.setFeedURL(feedURL); 
autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
```

EDIT2: Thanks to @JuanMa, I was able to get it working. Here is the code.

```
// auto update functionality

const {autoUpdater} = require('electron')

// local file system example: const feedURL = 'C:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\updates_folder';
// network file system example: const feedURL = '\\\\serverName\\updates_folder';

const feedURL = '\\\\serverName\\updates_folder';

app.on('ready', () => {
    autoUpdater.setFeedURL(feedURL);

    // auto update event listeners, these are fired as a result of  autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();

    autoUpdater.addListener("update-available", function(event) {

    });
    autoUpdater.addListener("update-downloaded", function(event,   releaseNotes, releaseName, releaseDate, updateURL) {

      //TODO: finess this a tad, as is after a few seconds of launching the app it will close without warning
      // and reopen with the update which could confuse the user and possibly cause loss of work

        autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
    });
    autoUpdater.addListener("error", function(error) {

    });
    autoUpdater.addListener("checking-for-update", function(event) {

    });
    autoUpdater.addListener("update-not-available", function(event) {

    });

    // tell squirrel to check for updates
    autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you including the autoUpdater module correctly?

```
const {autoUpdater} = require('electron')
```

If so try to execute the code after the app 'ready' event.

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  const feedURL = 'C:\\Users\\p00009970\\Desktop\\update_test';
  autoUpdater.setFeedURL(feedURL); 
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdates(); 
})
```

Comment: Including everything in app 'ready' got rid of the error but now I can't tell if it's executing updates or not, I've pushed an update but nothing is happening

Comment: Update: app ready definitely fixed my issue, my remaining issue was with corporate proxy crap. I'll update my question with finalized code.

Comment: glad I could help!